Only allow same value in column after first Insert
I am trying to create a trigger that only allows the user to insert the same value into a column after the first insert has been made. For example in the table below the user has entered Name = Jake and age = 29.



Name
Age




Jake
29



From this point onwards, the trigger on the name column should now only allow the user to enter the Name = Jake.



Name
Age




Jake
29


Jake
36



Code below is what I tried but I am getting a ORA-04091 error but I imagine this is because I am referencing the table itself in the trigger? Although I'm not sure
CREATE TRIGGER my_table
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF name ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
a_CurrName VARCHAR2(20BYTE);
BEGIN
SELECT name INTO a_CurrName FROM my_table WHERE ROWNUM=1;
IF a_CurrName IS NOT NULL THEN
   IF :new.name != a_CurrName
   THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'This table can only hold one unique name at any point' );
   END IF;
END IF;
END;


because you could never load real data. the first entry determines all the rest. there's no point. If you want to dedicate the entire table to Jake, put a check constraint on it to force it to always be Jake. Call it JAKES_TABLE. It wouldn't be good for anything else.

The table uses a FK constraint which only allows certain values (e.g. Jake, Paul, Simon) however once the user has selected a name, they should only be able to insert that name for the remainder. The use case is specific, and the inserts are only ever done manually (i.e. one record at a time)

I would recommend to do not set such restrictions in the database. Rather implement this logic in your application.

Out of curiosity... what is the business requirement here ? I could be wrong, but it looks like you're trying to implement functionality that can easily be achieved using 2 tables with a foreign key. A table NAMES would store JAKE and the AGES (name_id - fk to NAMES, age) would store all the ages for a specific name. Because there is a foreign key every age will always be linked to a single name.

@KoenLostrie in this case the table is referenced by an API and allows for users to define some parameters. In this case, the parameters for the call do not allow the user to enter mixed "Names"  however they can enter multiple "Ages". The table is wiped after the call is complete.

You can use a COMPOUND trigger:
CREATE TRIGGER my_table__same_name__trg
  FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OF name ON my_table
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  v_old_name  MY_TABLE.NAME%TYPE   := NULL;
BEFORE STATEMENT
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT name
    INTO   v_old_name
    FROM   my_table
    WHERE  ROWNUM=1;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      NULL;
  END BEFORE STATEMENT;
BEFORE EACH ROW
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF v_old_name IS NULL THEN
      v_old_name := :NEW.name;
    ELSIF v_old_name != :NEW.name THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'This table can only hold one unique name at any point' );
    END IF;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;  
END;
/

If you have the table:
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  age  NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT my_table__age_ge_0__chk CHECK ( age >= 0 )
);

Then:
INSERT INTO my_table (name, age) VALUES ('Alice', 26);

Works and afterwards:
INSERT INTO my_table (name, age) VALUES ('Betty', 27);

Raises the exception:
ORA-20001: This table can only hold one unique name at any point
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_ERLZSCAOAKYVIRYFNEFX.MY_TABLE__SAME_NAME__TRG", line 21
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_ERLZSCAOAKYVIRYFNEFX.MY_TABLE__SAME_NAME__TRG'

And trying to insert more rows with the same name works (both as single- and multi-row inserts):
INSERT INTO my_table (name, age) VALUES ('Alice', 30);

INSERT INTO my_table (name, age)
  SELECT 'Alice', 32 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Alice', 36 FROM DUAL;

And the table contains:



NAME
AGE




Alice
26


Alice
30


Alice
32


Alice
36



If you then try to insert multiple rows with different names into an empty table:
DELETE FROM my_table;

INSERT INTO my_table (name, age)
  SELECT 'Alice', 32 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Betty', 27 FROM DUAL;

Then you get the exception:
ORA-20001: This table can only hold one unique name at any point
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_ERLZSCAOAKYVIRYFNEFX.MY_TABLE__SAME_NAME__TRG", line 21
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_ERLZSCAOAKYVIRYFNEFX.MY_TABLE__SAME_NAME__TRG'

fiddle


The use case is specific, and the inserts are only ever done manually (i.e. one record at a time)

If that's so, then this might work for this specific use case.
Sample table:
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     name   VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
  4     age    NUMBER
  5  );

Table created.

Trigger:
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_biu_test
  2     BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  3     ON test
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  DECLARE
  6     l_name  test.name%TYPE;
  7  BEGIN
  8     SELECT MAX (t.name)
  9       INTO l_name
 10       FROM test t
 11      WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
 12
 13     IF :new.name <> l_name
 14     THEN
 15        raise_application_error (
 16           -20001,
 17           'This table can only hold one unique name at any point, and that''s ' || l_name);
 18     END IF;
 19  END;
 20  /

Trigger created.

Testing:
SQL> INSERT INTO test (name, age) VALUES ('Jake', 29);

1 row created.

According to requirement, only Jake's are allowed from now on:
SQL> INSERT INTO test (name, age) VALUES ('Jake', 36);

1 row created.

Can I insert someone else? No:
SQL> INSERT INTO test (name, age) VALUES ('Mike', 18);
INSERT INTO test (name, age) VALUES ('Mike', 18)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: This table can only hold one unique name at any point, and that's
Jake
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TEST", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TEST'


However, if what you said isn't entirely true and someone enters more than a single row at a time, you will get a mutating table error (although only Jake is being inserted):
SQL> INSERT INTO test (name, age)
  2     SELECT 'Jake', 50 FROM DUAL
  3     UNION ALL
  4     SELECT 'Jake', 60 FROM DUAL;
INSERT INTO test (name, age)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table SCOTT.TEST is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TEST", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TEST'


SQL>

